# How can I batch update all objects in User class (Parse.com, Android)?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, parse-server

I made a mistake initially and forgot to initialize my Array field (designs) upon user registration, so in my Parse dashboard the rows show up as `(undefined)`, where I would prefer them to be `[]`. I have to do this for about 5000 users. I tried the following code:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("User");
query.equalTo("designs", "(undefined)");
query.each(function(obj) {
  obj.set("designs", "[]");
  return obj.save();
}).then(function() {
  // All objects updated.
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

I think `(undefined)` should be something else, but I'm not sure what, as it's probably not a String. How can I solve this?

**Update: A second attempt. Is this getting closer?**

```
    private void updateAllRows(final int skip) {

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.setLimit(500);
    query.setSkip(skip);
    query.whereDoesNotExist("designs");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> results, ParseException e) {
            if (results.size() > 0) {

                // The query was successful.
                for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                    ParseUser user = results.get(i);
                    String[] designs = new String[0];
                    user.put("designs", Arrays.asList(designs));

                    try {
                        ParseUser.saveAll(results);
                        if (results.size() >= 500) {
                            updateAllRows(skip + 500); // make a recursion call with different skip value
                        }
                    } catch (ParseException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                Log.d(getClass().toString(), ": The batch job was successfully completed.");

            } else {
                // The query was unsuccessful.
                Log.d(getClass().toString(), ": The batch job was not successful.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I call teh above function with the following from my class's onCreate method:

```
int skip = 0;
updateAllRows(skip);
```

Is this the best way to go about this without using Cloud code?

**Error:**

```
08-08 12:38:43.034 24003-24053/? E/HttpOperation: [luq{checkandengageuser, getmobileexperiments}] Unexpected exception
                                                  java.io.IOException: 1 of 2 operations in the batch failed
                                                      at luj.a(PG:268)
                                                      at lth.o(PG:10642)
                                                      at ltc.a(PG:1402)
                                                      at lth.i(PG:154)
                                                      at ly.f(PG:51849)
                                                      at dsr.a(PG:1255)
                                                      at dsr.a(PG:20077)
                                                      at dsr.a(PG:706)
                                                      at dss.run(PG:1548)
                                                      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Did you got the answer of this query ?
im also facing one issue ,I want to fetch wherecontainsIn("CP") AND whereDoesnotExists both not working how to query this ?

Answer (score 5):

**JavaScript Version**
1. You can use Parse.Object.saveAll in order to save multiple objects in one service call
 2. You must use **limit** and **skip** in order to do it for 500 (or less) items at a time.
 3. You need to use **query.doesNotExist("designs");** in order to get all items which contain undefined in the design column

```js
function updateAllRows(skip) {

  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.limit(500);
  query.skip(skip);
  // get recors where designs is not exist or is undefined      
  query.doesNotExist("designs");

  query.find().then(function(results) {

    // if we got results then change the designs property 
    if (results.length > 0) {

      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var item = results[i];
        item.set("designs", []);
      }

      Parse.Object.saveAll(results).then(function() {
        // if we got 500 or more results then we know
        // that we have more results
        // otherwise we finish
        if (results.length >= 500) {
          updateAllRows(skip + 500); // make a recursion call with different skip value
        }

      }, function(err) {
        // error occured 
      });
    }
  }, function(error) {
    // error occured while trying to fetch data 
  });
};
```

**Android Java Version**

```
private void updateAllRows(final int skip){

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.setLimit(500);
    query.setSkip(skip);
    query.whereDoesNotExist("designs");

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(final List<ParseUser> users, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null){
                for (ParseUser user : users){
                    user.put("designs",new ArrayList<>());
                }

                // save all objects in one server call
                ParseObject.saveAllInBackground(users, new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {

                        if (e == null){
                            if (users.size() >= 500){
                                updateAllRows(skip + 500);
                            }
                        } else {
                            // error  while saving objects
                        }


                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

**BTW!** you can also create a cloud function in cloud code and trigger this function from the client

Comment: I noticed this was written in JavaScript. I updated my question to include a version in Java. Is the whole skipping bit still necessary? I also noticed you passed "skip" as a parameter. How does this factor in with Android?

Comment: it was written in JS because your example was in JavaScript.. I will post the android version

Comment: Oh sorry lol. My clipboard was literally messed up. I had an alternative in Java written there somewhere before.

Comment: One more thing, should I initialize my skip variable to 0? I use the following in my onCreate when calling the method: ``int skip = 0;
        updateAllRows(skip);``.

Comment: I am getting an error with your code. I've logged the exception above.

Comment: Can you please run this function with skip = 0 but comment out the updateAllRows(skip + 500); so it will run only once and check if it works ?

Comment: In both cases, where ``updateAllRows(skip + 500`` is hidden or not, I am returned the error case, which I logged with ``Log.w(getClass().toString(), "The batch job is not successful.");``. I feel like ``query.whereDoesNotExist("designs")``, isn't doing what it should be doing? The column is named correctly and there are definitely ``(undefined)`` items in the appropriate rows.

Comment: try to change 500 to 10 for in all places and try again. maybe it is due to some limitation on the server side.

Comment: Changed to 10 and still getting the error message unfortunately :(

Comment: you are using parse.com or parse-server open source?

Comment: Still using Parse.com, not parse-server yet. Planning on changing soon but need to fix this before that either way.

Comment: Hypothetically, what if the first 500 rows don't have an ``(undefined)`` value in one of the rows?

Comment: So it will ignore those rows.. you will not get them in your query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120420/discussion-between-ran-hassid-and-bluemunch).

Comment: I tested the javascript and it works, but I modify the code abit.
          Parse.Object.saveAll(results, {
            success: () => resolve(true),
            error: () => reject(new Error()),
          });

Answer (score 0):

Javascript version:

```
async updateAllRows(skip) {
    const query = new Parse.Query(Question);
    query.limit(500);
    query.skip(skip);
    query.doesNotExist("update");
    try {
      const results = await query.find();
      for (const result of results) {
        result.set('update', 'your update')
      }
      await Parse.Object.saveAll(results)
      if (results.length >= 500){
        updateAllRows(skip + 500).then().catch();
      }
    } catch (e) {
    }
  }
```